# Multiply across dataframes by column values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, substring, mapply

I am looking to multiply data across two different dataframes. The input is dynamic so the number of IDs per team is not constant. I've included a sample set of data below.

```
Branch  ID-1  Time-1  ID-2  Time-2  ID-3  Time-3
Texas   BKP   5.5     LMG   2.8     DDP   8.9
Maine   BQQ   11      BKP   8.1     OLW   3.0
NYork   DDP   2.0     ADD   6.5     BQQ   0.4
```

There are hundreds of branches that could utilize thousands of IDs, so the below is just a small subset I've created. We also receive a cost dataframe for all IDs similar to below:

```
ID     Cost
ADD    4.50
BKP    11.99
BQQ    1.50
DDP    8.99
LMG    24.99
OLW    29.99
```

I am trying to find the cost by ID per branch and I'm able to go by Substrings,  but joining the second dataframe is where I'm running into trouble. The output that I need would look like this:

```
Branch  ID-1  Time-1  ID-2  Time-2  ID-3  Time-3  Cost-1  Cost-2  Cost-3
Texas   BKP   5.5     LMG   2.8     DDP   8.9     65.945  69.972  80.011
Maine   BQQ   11      BKP   8.1     OLW   3.0     16.50   97.119  89.97
NYork   DDP   2.0     ADD   6.5     BQQ   0.4     17.98   29.25   0.6
```

I know this isn't the prettiest output, but unfortunately it's the output needed. I'm very grateful for any help you are able to provide with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(df1), id = 1,
     measure.vars = patterns(c("^ID","^Time")),
     value.name = c("ID","Time")
     )[df2, on = .(ID), Cost := Time * i.Cost
       ][, dcast(.SD, Branch ~ variable, value.var = c("ID","Time","Cost"))]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    Branch ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 Time_1 Time_2 Time_3 Cost_1 Cost_2 Cost_3
> 1:  Maine  BQQ  BKP  OLW   11.0    8.1    3.0 16.500 97.119 89.970
> 2:  NYork  DDP  ADD  BQQ    2.0    6.5    0.4 17.980 29.250  0.600
> 3:  Texas  BKP  LMG  DDP    5.5    2.8    8.9 65.945 69.972 80.011
> ```

---

Used data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Branch = c("Texas", "Maine", "NYork"), ID.1 = c("BKP", "BQQ", "DDP"), Time.1 = c(5.5, 11, 2), 
                      ID.2 = c("LMG", "BKP", "ADD"), Time.2 = c(2.8, 8.1, 6.5), ID.3 = c("DDP", "OLW", "BQQ"), Time.3 = c(8.9, 3, 0.4)), 
                 .Names = c("Branch", "ID.1", "Time.1", "ID.2", "Time.2", "ID.3", "Time.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("ADD", "BKP", "BQQ", "DDP", "LMG", "OLW"), Cost = c(4.5, 11.99, 1.5, 8.99, 24.99, 29.99)),
                 .Names = c("ID", "Cost"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jaap! I received an error when i had tried to use the above solution with the sample df. 'Error in `[.data.table`(melt(setDT(df), id = 1, measure.vars = patterns(c("^ID\\.",  : 
  Column(s) [ID] not found in x'.

Comment: @btaek Could you try with `patterns(c("^ID","^Time"))` or `patterns(c("^ID-","^Time-"))`? Both should work and I've updated my answer with the first option. You probably got that error because in my columnnames there was a dot instead of a hyphen (see also the used data I included in my answer).

Comment: that worked perfect - thanks! Not all branches may have use the same number of IDs so they are read as NAs initially. I've been going around this by assigning 0 values to all numeric columns based on a substring, would you recommend any alternative route?

Comment: @btaek why just leave them as `NA`?

Answer (score 0):

using Base R:

```
dat3 = merge(reshape(dat1,matrix(2:ncol(dat1),2),idv=1,dir="long",ids=dat1$Branch),dat2,by.x="ID.1",by.y="ID")

 reshape(transform(dat3,Cost=Cost * Time.1)[order(dat3$time),],idvar = "Branch",dir="wide")

  Branch ID.1.1 Time.1.1 Cost.1 ID.1.2 Time.1.2 Cost.2 ID.1.3 Time.1.3 Cost.3
2  Texas    BKP      5.5 65.945    LMG      2.8 69.972    DDP      8.9 80.011
4  Maine    BQQ     11.0 16.500    BKP      8.1 97.119    OLW      3.0 89.970
6  NYork    DDP      2.0 17.980    ADD      6.5 29.250    BQQ      0.4  0.600
```